# Generate full width character string in R

Tags: r, character-encoding, stringr

In R, how can I make the following:

convert this string: `"my test string"`

to something like this ( a full width character string): `"ｍｙ  ｔｅｓｔ  ｓｔｒｉｎｇ"`

is there a way to do this through hexidecimal character encodings?

Thanks for your help, I'm really not sure how to even start. Perhaps something with `{stringr}`

I'm trying to get an output similar to what I would expect from this online conversion tool:

http://www.linkstrasse.de/en/%EF%BD%86%EF%BD%95%EF%BD%8C%EF%BD%8C%EF%BD%97%EF%BD%89%EF%BD%84%EF%BD%94%EF%BD%88%EF%BC%8D%EF%BD%83%EF%BD%8F%EF%BD%8E%EF%BD%96%EF%BD%85%EF%BD%92%EF%BD%94%EF%BD%85%EF%BD%92

Comment: I don't know how-to rewrite the following Python code snippet in R, sorry. `''.join([chr(ord(x)+0xFEE0) if ord(x) in range(33,127) else x for x in "my test string"])` returns `'ｍｙ ｔｅｓｔ ｓｔｒｉｎｇ'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using a function from the archived [`Nippon` package](https://github.com/cran/Nippon). This is the `han2zen` function, which can be found [here](https://github.com/cran/Nippon/blob/master/R/zen2han.R).

```
x <- "my test string"

han2zen <- function(s){
  stopifnot(is.character(s))
  zenEisu <- paste0(intToUtf8(65295 + 1:10), intToUtf8(65312 + 1:26),
                    intToUtf8(65344 + 1:26))
  zenKigo <- c(65281, 65283, 65284, 65285, 65286, 65290, 65291,
               65292, 12540, 65294, 65295, 65306, 65307, 65308,
               65309, 65310, 65311, 65312, 65342, 65343, 65372,
               65374)
  s <- chartr("0-9A-Za-z", zenEisu, s)
  s <- chartr('!#$%&*+,-./:;<=>?@^_|~', intToUtf8(zenKigo), s)
  s <- gsub(" ", intToUtf8(12288), s)
  return(s)
}


han2zen(x)

# [1] "ｍｙ　ｔｅｓｔ　ｓｔｒｉｎｇ"
```